# how to pass Gitlab CI variable as a Traefik traefik.http.routers.container_name.rule label value

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, traefik

In Gitlab CI I'm trying to set Traefik labels while building an image in order to register it in the Traefik Service. This is how it's done:

```
- docker build -t $IMAGE . --label traefik.http.routers.$SERVICE_NAME.rule="Host(`$SERVICE_URL`)" --label traefik.enable=true
```

and this is how it is interpreted:

```
Step 7/7 : LABEL traefik.http.routers.socialmedia-service-master.rule=Host()
 ---> Running in c67fe595032a
```

both $SERVICE_URL and $SERVICE_NAME definitely set. 
How can I make it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the back ticks, like so:

```
docker build -t $IMAGE . --label traefik.http.routers.$SERVICE_NAME.rule="Host(\`$SERVICE_URL\`)" --label traefik.enable=true
```